# Converting hexadecimal string to floating point value

Tags: arduino-ide

I am reading data from an energy meter over modbus protocol and I am getting hex values from there. I want to convert that hex string to floating point value.
For example - 0x416f0000 denotes a value of 14.9375.[Reference](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/)

Can anyone please help me how to do it on Arduino IDE?

Comment: You mean Modbus ASCII, right? Non-ASCII Modbus doesn't use hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do indeed have an ASCII string of hexadecimal numbers (and not a
raw binary float), then your best option may be to do the conversion in
two steps:

1. convert the string to a 32 bit unsigned number using
   [`strtoul()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaea44aa48bda8261f794dcb2d1e7ab2b2)
2. reinterpret the binary pattern of this integer as a float.

For example, the following program:

```c++
void setup() {
    const char modbus_data[] = "416F0000";
    union {
        uint32_t i;
        float f;
    } data;
    data.i = strtoul(modbus_data, NULL, 16);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(data.f, 4);
}

void loop(){}
```

prints `14.9375`.

Note that for `strtoul()` to function properly, the hex string must be
followed by a character that is not a valid hex digit (a `\0` in the
example above).